# jetty-maven-plugin with OpenEJB

Tags: java, maven, ejb, maven-jetty-plugin, openejb

I'm trying to create the most basic proof-of-concept for integration testing a Java webapp that has an EJB dependency.  I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186348/maven-ear-module-and-ejb-dependencies-tests) article, which looks close to what I'm trying to do.

To create the simplest webapp possible, I used `mvn archetype:generate` and selected the 'maven-archetype-webapp' option.

Then I altered the `pom.xml` file to look like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.jwleeman</groupId>
  <artifactId>ridgefield</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ridgefield Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>ridgefield</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                  <systemProperty>
                    <name>java.naming.factory.initial</name>
                    <value>org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory</value>
                  </systemProperty>
                  <systemProperty>
                    <name>java.naming.factory.url.pkgs</name>
                    <value>org.mortbay.naming</value>
                  </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>100</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9099</stopPort>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>9090</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>                   
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

However, when I run `mvn clean install`, I get the following exception:

```
2015-01-06 11:29:23.524:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.12.v20130726
2015-01-06 11:29:23.628:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/Users/jeffreyleeman/maven-experiments/ridgefield/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/jeffreyleeman/maven-experiments/ridgefield/src/main/webapp/
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
```

Can anyone help me out with what might be happening?  Thanks so much!

**UPDATE:**

So I got past the first error above by moving the `openejb-core` dependency to the jetty-maven-plugin itself, so under the `<plugin>` element, I added the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(and removed this `<dependency/>` from its original place in the POM.)

Now I get the following error when running `mvn clean install`:

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/ridgefield,file:/Users/jeffreyleeman/maven-experiments/ridgefield/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/jeffreyleeman/maven-experiments/ridgefield/src/main/webapp/
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/env" not found.
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:197)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:126)
```

Any ideas?